# Can you hide table header css styling (sort arrow) by collapsing colgroup element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, colgroup

I have an html table:

```
        <colgroup>
            <col id="userid">
            <col id="username">
            <col id="time">
            <col id="logout">
            <col id="ipaddress">
            <col id="lastaccess">
            <col id="event">
            <col id="errordetail">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="sortable">User Id</th>
                <th class="sortable">User Name</th>
                <th class="sortable">Time</th>
                <th class="sortable">Logout</th>
                <th class="sortable">IP Address</th>
                <th class="sortable">Last Access</th>
                <th class="sortable">Event</th>
                <th class="sortable">Error Detail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="login_history"></tbody>
    </table>
```

Where I add a css class to col elements to collapse the columns:

`.hide_table_column {  visibility: collapse; }`

I have more css styling on the table header elements (essentially a sort icon using only css):

```
th.sortable {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

th.sortable::after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
    border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

th.sortable.asc::after {
    border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
}
```

The problem is that the arrow on the th element still displays even after I've collapsed the column.

[Table with last column collapsed still shows the arrow from styling the th element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSmCG.png)

I don't want to add more logic to remove/add the sortable class and instead am looking for a way to keep it simple and hide everything by collapsing the column by adding that .hide_table_column css class to the col elements. Is this possible? Would I need to use a proper arrow icon instead of pure css?